# Style Outside Title of Fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Does anyone know how to style the title for the 'outside' version for fancybox? You have inside,outside, and over... im trying to style the outside version. I tried setting the global title tag in my css, unfortunately that seems to have no effect. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I just went through this.
You change the images below to the look you want keeping the same dimensions, 
then change the these parts of the css.

```
#fancybox-title-left {
    background-image: url("fancy_title_left.png");
    background-position:0;
}
#fancybox-title-right {
    background-image: url("fancy_title_right.png");
    background-position:0;
}

#fancybox-title-main {
    background-image: url("fancy_title_main.png");
    background-position: 0 ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use firebug to see the class's, id's etc applied and then just override in your own css.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to modify the title

```
.fancybox-title-float-wrap .child {
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: none;
}
```